# AR core giving error in ar_core module flutter

Tags: flutter, augmented-reality, arcore

I am new to flutter. I am using AR core provided by google. But I get this error at compiletime:

> flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\arcore_flutter_plugin-0.0.10\android\src\main\kotlin\com\difrancescogianmarco\arcore_flutter_plugin\ArCoreView.kt: (241, 38): Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onActivityCreated(@NonNull p0: Activity, @Nullable p1: Bundle?): Unit defined in android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks

You can see my code [here](https://github.com/JoelNadar-TheSorceror/Augmented-Reality-in-flutter)

is this error specific to my version or is it an error in the properties?
Also I have enabled AndroidX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in the flutter plugin that needs to be corrected.

Go to ArCoreView.kt file in Flutter plugin at

\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.flutter-io.cn\arcore_flutter_plugin-0.0.10\android\src\main\kotlin\com\difrancescogianmarco\arcore_flutter_plugin

remove "?" from onActivityCreated as below

i.e.
Replace

```
override fun onActivityCreated( activity: Activity?, savedInstanceState: Bundle? )
```

By

```
override fun onActivityCreated( activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle? )
```

This resolved my problem